Help with Doran's book GA for Physicists
On page 213 equation (6.262) There is a formula which involves the Riemann tensor $a \cdot \mathbf R (b \land c) + c \cdot \mathbf R (a \land b) + b \cdot \mathbf R (c \land a) = 0 $. Then Doran writes "This equation tells us that a vector quantity vanishes for all trivector $a \land b \land c$, which provides a set of $n^2 (n-1) (n-2)/6$ scalar equations". It seems to me that there are only $n (n-1) (n-2)/6$ such equations, and I don't understand why the extra $n$ multiplier. If on the RHS there was a vector, not the scalar zero, I would understand the extra $n$.

It is the vector zero! In fact in GA there is no distinction; the same $0$ is a scalar and a vector (and a bivector etc.).

@mr_e_man I meant to say "If on the RHS there was a nonzero vector, not the zero vector" etc. So your commnet, while correct, doesn't help me.

You have a system of $n(n-1)(n-2)/6$ vector equations. A single vector equation is equivalent to $n$ scalar equations. E.g. the vector equation $$(y+z)\mathbf e_1+(z+x)\mathbf e_2+(x+y)\mathbf e_3=0$$ is equivalent to the $3$ scalar equations $$y+z=0,\quad z+x=0,\quad x+y=0.$$
